# PyCharm using Anaconda python.exe with Modules fails - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, pyside

I'm trying to use Pycharm 2018.3 on Windows 10 with my Anaconda env (python.exe).
It doesn't work, I don't know why.

The Project Interpreter is set to the python.exe correctly.

In VSC or Spyder and even in Jupyter Notebook, the code works. 
Only Pycharm doesn't find the modules.

This code:

```
print("Hello")
import sys
from qtpy import QtWidgets
```

gets this error message:

```
Hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 199, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PycharmProjects/ui/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from qtpy import QtWidgets
  File "D:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 205, in <module>
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I googled a lot of topics dealing with similar topics, but none solved the problem on my side.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Some additional information:

======================================== cmd.exe

```
C:\Users\Mega>python
Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from qtpy import QtWidgets
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 199, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "d:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 205, in <module>
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
>>>
```

====================================== Anaconda prompt

```
(base) C:\Users\Mega>python
Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from qtpy import QtWidgets
>>>
```

====================================== Jupyter Notebook

in Jupyter Notebook this works

```
import sys
from qtpy import QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
window.setWindowTitle("HAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALLO")
window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and as I said in Visual Studio Code and Spyer it works too.

I have only one env in conda
(base) C:\Users\Mega>conda env list

## conda environments:

#
base                  *  D:\Python\Anaconda3

(base) C:\Users\Mega>

My pathes:

```
d:\Python\Anaconda3\python37.zip
d:\Python\Anaconda3\DLLs
d:\Python\Anaconda3\Lib
d:\Python\Anaconda3
d:\Python\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages
d:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32
d:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
d:\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pythonwin
```

Comment: Can you try to type `conda install -c anaconda pyside` in the Pycharm embedded terminal? And then try to run your code again.

Comment: The command isn't found from the Terminal in PyCharm. Even when I'm running it from the installation directory e.g. D:\Python\Anaconda3

Comment: In a terminal (whichever) that recognize the conda command, can you do `conda env list`. Check which environment is activated (the one with the star). If it is not the one of your project do: `source activate <the_name_of_the_env>`. Then try the command `conda install -c anaconda pyside` and try running your code again. (you can also check which terminal Pycharm uses in the Settings and change it if you want)

Comment: conda env list shows : (base) C:\Users\Mega>conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  D:\Python\Anaconda3                                       I'm going to try the installation of PySide. Till now, it is still analyzing the env :-)

Comment: What are VSC or Spider doing differently? Those IDEs are using the conda env and the code runs without problems. That is why, I don't think the problem belongs to the conda installation. I guess it must be something PyCharm does the others don't do.

Comment: I cannot install PySide from Anaconda prompt. The solving-environment process doesn't end :-(

Comment: Let's try to update conda as described in: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/9741 I'm running out of ideas. You can also try to Invalidate the caches of Pycharm. `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart`

Comment: Did not help. I added some more information to post 1. Maybe you have one last idea what to do. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new env and tried that with PyCharm. Now, it is working. Sometimes, I don't know why and when, the default env of Anaconda doesn't work with Pycharm.